# FileNotFoundException in java/javafx searching a solution

Tags: java, javafx

Previously that was my code:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Bundesliga extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        PlayerManager league = new PlayerManager();
        league.uruchom();
    }
}
```

Of course there is another class PlayerManager but I think it isn't needed. Everything worked very well and there were no errors. Then I tried to modify it using Javafx. There is a modified one:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Bundesliga extends Application {
    Stage window;
    Scene scene1;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        launch(args);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws FileNotFoundException {
        PlayerManager league = new PlayerManager();
        window = primaryStage;

        Button button1 = new Button("Uruchom program");
        button1.setOnAction(e -> league.uruchom());

        StackPane layout = new StackPane();
        layout.getChildren().add(button1);
        scene1 = new Scene(layout, 600, 300);

        window.setScene(scene1);
        window.setTitle("Title here");
        window.show();
    }
}
```

I wanted to run my code by clicking on button, but when I'm trying to compile it, the error occours: **"Bundesliga.java:24: error: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown                   button1.setOnAction(e -> league.uruchom());** I don't know how to solve that, because my methods throw FileNotFoundException. Please help me.

Comment: http://crunchify.com/better-understanding-on-checked-vs-unchecked-exceptions-how-to-handle-exception-better-way-in-java/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `league.uruchom()` is expected to throw a `FileNotFoundException`, but your lambda is overriding the `actionPerformed` method, which does not have this Exception in its signature.

You should handle the exception in the lambda's method body. At worst, you could convert the exception to a `RuntimeException` to handle later, but I don't recommend this.

Comment: Thank you, Could you tell me how  I can handle the exception in the lambda's method body? I would be really grateful.